# BSON can't serialize BigDecimal

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb, serialization, bson

I recently deployed the Oj JSON parser to production which loads floating point numbers to BigDecimals by default.
When I insert the hashes parsed by Oj to MongoDB I get an exception that says that BSON can't serialize BigDecimals.
This is the exception message:

> BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize the Numeric type BigDecimal as
>   BSON; only Bignum, Fixnum, and Float are supported.

I can configure Oj to convert floating point numbers to float but I'm guessing that there's a performance penalty.

I'm using an old BSON gem (version 1.12.5, current is 4.0.1) and I haven't checked if a newer version already handles this for me. I'm not sure if I can upgrade since I'm stuck with MongoDB 2.x for the time being.

Is there a performance penalty if I switch from BigDecimal to float? Is there a better way to allow the BSON library to serialize BigDecimal?

Comment: You can use Ruby's [`Benchmark` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) and test it out by writing a small program

Comment: I guess I can but if someone has already done it before it will save me some work and provide information for others (which is the whole purpose of SO).

Comment: Mongoid 3.x (uses moped) stores BigDecimal as a string in mongo due to floating point precision.

Comment: Floats are acceptable in this case. I can convert to float when inserting to MongoDB.

Comment: Facing the same with Mongodb 3.2 + BSON 4.1